# Prove that set of all non principal ideals of an integral domain has a maximal element

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

In an integral domain $R$ the prime ideals are principal ideals. (given)

So my attempt was using the Zorn lemma. We assume that there exists a chain of non principal ideals so by set inclusion the chain will be partially ordered by set inclusion.

Now the chain will have a maximal element. My reason is like this that let $I_1$ be the ideal generated by $(a, b) $ , then this ideal will be contained in the ideal $I_2=(a, b, c) $ so I think that it will have a upper bound which will be the whole ring itself. Now by Zorn lemma there will be a maximal element.  Is this OK?

Comment: Your first sentence is not true in general.

Comment: I am confused. The ring $\mathbb Z[X]$ is an integral domain and the ideal $(X,2)$ is prime, however, cannot be generated by one element. Also, if you take $R$ to be non-Noetherian domain (e.g. a polynomial ring over countably many variables), one can find counterexamples to the statement you are trying to prove.

Comment: The first statement is something that is mentioned in the question @Marktmeister